# 1970s Ghost Story series with black and white illustrations and a story of a girl who is friends with a girl ghost

Tags: story-identification, books, ghost

In the late 70's my elementary school library had, as best I can recall, a series of  smallish, library-bound books that were a series of spooky stories for kids. They were quite eerie and had black and white illustrations that were similar to the kind in *Scary Stories to Tell in the Dark*, but this was well before that book was published.  It is also not Horror Tales ed. Elwood.  In terms of the date they seemed pretty new circa 1978-79.

The one story I remember was about a girl who was friends with another girl who happened to be a ghost.

Comment: Possibly the Armada Ghost books?

Comment: Or the Fontana Books of Great Ghost Stories? A new edition of those and the Armada Ghost Books came out once a year, starting in the 60s and continuing into the 80s. Your library could easily have had them. Mine did!